# How to use Remote File within Imagemagick Command in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, imagick

I´m currently using Imagemagick on a shared hosted Webspace. Imagemagick is also installed on this webspace. Its versionString is `ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-06-26` and its versionNumber is `1673`.

Now my Question or problem:
I want to convert a `REMOTE FILE` for example https://www.google.com/favicon.ico to a png image to use it afterwards. To achieve this I´m currently using this PHP Script:

```
<?php
   exec( "/usr/bin/convert convert https://www.google.com/favicon.ico favicon.png" );
?>
```

But this command doesn´t create the file `favicon.png` in the same folder. But if I download the favicon.ico file and store it on the server I can use this command and it works perfectly:

```
<?php
   exec( "/usr/bin/convert convert favicon.ico favicon.png" );
?>
```

So how can I use a remote file with the convert command in imagemagick without storing the file on my server? I also tried to create a new Image Object with `$Imagick->getImageBlob();` -> https://secure.php.net/manual/de/imagick.getimageblob.php and inserted the output into the exec(); command like this

```
<?php
exec( "/usr/bin/convert convert " . $Imagick->getImageBlob() . "favicon.png" );
?>
```

in PHP. But it only showed the error that this Command could be an attack.

I hope you can help me to solve this problem and thanks in advance!

`PS: I can not edit anything in the Imagemagick settings or update the class/package either.`

Comment: If you command fails to create a file, it is likely because HTTPS is prevented for security reasons. That is likely why you get that warning. That restriction would be set in the ImageMagick policy.xml file and is likely the default. But only your hosting provider would be able to undo that restriction. You may want to use wget or curl to download the file and pipe it into ImageMagick, if your hosting provider permits the use of either of those tools.

Comment: Thx @fmw42 for your answer. Yes curl is available. I will try it and contact my hosting provider tommorrow to ask if https is prevented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -O- https://www.google.com/favicon.ico | convert  ico:- favicon.jpg
```

Explanation:
You should download the file with the "wget" and output into a standard output then pipe it to "convert".
"ico:-" - this means input file type "image/ico" and take it from stdin.

Or just use:

```
 $imagick = new Imagick();
 $imagick->readImageBlob("https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
 $image->writeImage('favicon.png');
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you! Also for your explanation. It woooorks. :) Thumbs up.

Comment: Oh but I suggest to use favicon.png instead of favicon.jpg, otherwise the output image will look a bit fuzzy. PNG solves the problem.

Comment: wget -O- https://www.google.com/favicon.ico | convert  ico:- favicon.png